# Hiding entire select drop down menu on click without showing the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide the entire drop down menu on a click event but there is a bit of a delay and it shows the menu for a split second. **I want it to hide without showing the menu at all.**

Is it possible to either:

- Not display the menu at all on click

OR

- Hide the entire select box without it showing the menu on click

Happy to use `JavaScript` or `jQuery`.

HTML

```
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","select",function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Current code is:
https://jsfiddle.net/La9mnfhc/1/

Comment: If you don't want the dropdown, why do you use a select? Use a hidden input, develop your own thing for the menu and populate the field with whatever you want to send in the form.

Comment: The reason is that I'm populating the select box with ~1000 options in JavaScript and don't want the original menu showing when clicking the select box which has just a preselected option.

It will show the menu after it has been populated.

Comment: why don't you invert the relationship? have it hidden by default and then show it on some other event?

Comment: Then just disable the select until your process is complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the options or select itself, on mouseover you can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("mouseover","select",function(){
    $(this).find('option').hide();//hide options
    $(this).hide();//hide select itself
  });
});
```

But if you want to use click event, 'click' event for select would be something like 'change' event.

Comment: Hiding options isn't very compatible across browsers unfortunately.

Comment: Can you be specific?

Answer (score 0):

you just have to do a simple trick, have that select to be hidden by default on the page load and you can make it visible after the selection as you want. just add `style="display:none"` as the attribute in the html of `select` element and make it `show()` after.